# Google App Engine Launcher is not running my hello world for Python Mac

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine

I have tried all the existing resources but to no avail.

here is my app.yaml code:

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

Here is my webapp2 code:

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

All in my hello_world directory. I proceed to add existing application and point to the hello_world directory where helloworld.py (webapp2) script and the app.yaml code are living. I hit run on Google App Engine and it just stays loading, it never completes. Therefore, my `http://localhost:8080/` page never loads.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `application:` line in your `app.yaml`.

You're probably also gonna need to list the 3rd party webapp2 in the libraries section, something like this:

```
libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```