# Google App Engine Launcher not completing loading

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

Good day all. First time stack overflow has not previously answered an issue that I have. My problem is exactly like the one posted here, except I am running windows:

[Google App Engine Launcher is not running my hello world for Python Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31174826/google-app-engine-launcher-is-not-running-my-hello-world-for-python-mac)

The only thing the log gives me is this

> 2016-08-18 13:39:13 Running command:
>   "['C:\Users\Kesi\Desktop\Documents\Computer
>   Science\Udacity\Intro to backend\hello-udacity\main.py',
>   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py',
>   '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000',
>   'C:\Users\Kesi\Desktop\Documents\Computer Science\Udacity\Intro
>   to backend\hello-udacity']"

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: you seem to have an undesired `'C:\Users\Kesi\Desktop\Documents\Computer Science\Udacity\Intro to backend\hello-udacity\main.py'` preceeding the `dev_appserver.py` cmd (which is the one to execute). You need to configure your execution utility or the IDE you're using to remove that. I'm not familiar with windoze, can't help w/ the details, tho.

Comment: In the google app engine preferences section there is a place to specify the path to executable python file. Ive updated this to execute the dev_appserver.py. However it still hangs and now gives this message:   Running command: "['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'C:\\Users\\Kesi\\Desktop\\Documents\\Computer Science\\Udacity\\Intro to backend\\hello-udacity']"

Comment: now you have `dev_appserver.py` twice - not OK. Sounds like that space may be referring to the actual python executable (from your python installation). Which could be a `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` (plus path maybe) according to this: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts. I'm mostly guessing here...

Comment: Yes it was. A friend explained it to me that way as well and he was actually able to show me. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comments to an answer.

The 1st argument in the command list from your message is `'C:\Users\Kesi\Desktop\Documents\Computer Science\Udacity\Intro to backend\hello-udacity\main.py'`, preceeding the `dev_appserver.py` suggests a configuration problem.

In the google app engine preferences section there is a place to specify the path to executable python file. That should not be set to your app's python file (as you have it), but to the actual python executable (from your python installation) - which executes `dev_appserver.py` (the 2nd arg in the command list) which in turn loads the subsequent command list args including one which is the one specifying your app code's location - the last one in your case.

The python executable could be a `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` according to the [Executing scripts](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts) section of [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#) doc:

> Python scripts (files with the extension .py) will be executed by
>   **python.exe** by default. This executable opens a terminal, which stays open even if the program uses a GUI. If you do not want this to
>   happen, use the extension .pyw which will cause the script to be
>   executed by **pythonw.exe** by default (both executables are located
>   in the top-level of your Python installation directory). This
>   suppresses the terminal window on startup.